# Can I use the phrase "initiate solutions throughout others"

Tags: expressions

Is this a valid English phrase?
I am trying to say - initiate solution snd build them by inspiring, supporting and encouraging others.

EDIT:
The full sentence is:

> Be able to manage my work better and to initiate solutions throughout
>   others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Throughout" means everywhere:

> War has been mankind's companion **throughout** history
>  The
>   plague spread **throughout** Europe.

"Through" is closer to the word you need as it can connote instrumentality:

> Only **through** justice can you maintain peace.

But the word is a bit odd with respect to people.  I think you mean solving problems by engaging others.

Comment: Agree with @deadrat; it might help you to choose the right words if you consider the precise relationship between the "others" and the "solutions."  For instance, do you mean that (1) others will you initiate the solutions; (2) others will help you build the solutions; and/or (3) working with others (in general) will help you initiate and/or build solutions.

Comment: @vstrong I think the best choce would be: (2) others will help you build the solutions.

Comment: Then you might consider something like "initiate solutions and work with others to build [or effect, or implement] those solutions."

Answer (score 0):

The full sentence would provide better context to determine if the word usage is correct, but to use the words you're mentioning properly, one sentence could be:

> "We initiate solutions through inspiring, supporting and encouraging
>   others."

Comment: Updated the question with the full sentence.